# If $T: R^2 \rightarrow R$ is a linear transformation then

Tags: linear-algebra

$T: R^2 \rightarrow R$ is a linear transformation such that $T(v) \neq 0$ for some $v$  in $R^2$ then T is

- one-to-one
- onto
- $nullity(T) = 0$
- none of the above

My first thought was that since $dim(R^2) > dim(R)$ then T cannot be one-to-one. I was inclined to put none of the above, but I feel $T(v) \neq 0$ is a crucial piece of information. Is this function onto? If so why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ is onto. Indeed, let $v\in R^2$ be such that $T(v)\ne 0$.
Let $\alpha$ be any real number. Then
$$
T\left(\frac{\alpha}{T(v)}v\right)=\frac{\alpha}{T(v)}T(v)=\alpha.
$$

Comment: Don't understand the notation of the first equation you wrote (with $\alpha$)

Comment: I simplify my solution.

Comment: Ok, so you showed that for a number $\alpha \in R^2$, there exists $\frac{\alpha}{T(v)} \times v$ such that T of this number is $\alpha$?

Comment: No. For any $\alpha\in R$, there exists $v_\alpha=\frac{\alpha}{T(v)}v\in R^2$ such that $T(v_\alpha)=\alpha$.. Hence $T$ is onto from $R^2$ to $R$.

Comment: Okay cool, just wondering how did you even think of this? How does knowing that the image of some vector is non-zero help you conclude it is onto? Intuitively that is.

Comment: I try to construct counter-example for each statement. $T(x,y)=x+y$ is not one to one mapping and Nulity$T$=dim(Ker$T$)$=1\ne 0$. I can not construct counter-example for the case $T$ being onto. Hence, i think that $T$ is onto and use the assumption $T(v)\ne 0$ to prove this fact.

Comment: @kevinzakka: The image of a linear transformation is a subspace of the codomain (which you should prove if you didn't know). In particular, every scalar multiple of $T(v)$ is in the image of $T.$ Since $T(v)$ is a nonzero real, then *every* real is a scalar multiple of $T(v).$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $T(\Bbb R^2)$ is a vector subspace of $\Bbb R$ and that $dimT(\Bbb R^2) \le dim \Bbb R = 1 $. So $dimT(\Bbb R^2)$ is either $1$ or $0$. But $T \neq 0$ therefore $dimT(\Bbb R^2)=1=dim \Bbb R$ and since $T(\Bbb R^2)$ is a vector subspace of $\Bbb R$ they are produced by the same basis, so they are equal. So $T$ is onto!

Answer (score -1):

Nullspace is not empty so the dimension of Nullspace is not zero.
By rank and nullity theorem $\text{dim}(N(T)) + \text{dim}(R(T)) = \text{dim}(R^2) = 2$.
But $dim(N(T))$ is also not $2$ because not for all $v$, $T(v) = 0$.
Thus $\text{dim} (N(T)) = 1$ which implies $\text{dim}(R(T)) = 1$.
since R(T) is subspace of $R^2$ and $\text{dim}(R(T)) = \text{dim}(R)$ then $R(T) = R$ which means that $T$ is onto.